# Bash User Prompt Default Input Text

Tags: bash

Is it possible to add text, as if the user typed something, to the current bash user input prompt (not the information display prompt, input after the `$` or `#`).

For example, (stupid example)

Say I want a command that adds 'sudo' to the next prompt after pressing enter

```
user@computer ~$ runAsSudo # ENTER PRESSED
user@computer ~$ sudo █    # █ is the cursor
```

My real application for this is having a command that undoes something, for example a copy, but instead of running it or asking for y/n, it simply adds it to the input prompt where the user can do whatever.

```
user@computer ~$ cp myFile /some/long/path/      # ENTER PRESSED
user@computer ~$ undo                            # ENTER PRESSED
user@computer ~$ cp /some/long/path/ myfile █    # █ is the cursor
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do this. You could push a history entry with the reversed command which would let them use `!!` to run it but that's all I can think of that isn't a prompt or just running it.

Comment: Question: do you expect the semi-entered command to disappear if the user repeatedly press backspace?

Comment: @mauro No really a requirement, doesnt really matter. 
Edit. Rereading your question, my goal is to have the semi command be regular text, as if it was pasted or typed in by user, so yes i was hoping it woud behave as regular text

Answer (score 2):

The Readline library doesn't have this functionality (although for reference, you might want to check out `zsh`, whose built-in line editor does have it). In this case, though, you can use history expansion in place of your `undo` command. For instance, typing `!!`, then Meta-^ (usually Alt-^, but possibly Esc-^, depending on your setup) will expand the history expansion without actually executing the command, letting the user edit the command.