# Automatically populate python input prompt with default value

Tags: python, input

The code:

```
input("Type your input here:)
```

displays as:

```
Type your input here:
```

I want to automatically populate the input window with text that can be cleared by pressing backspace so the display looks like:

```
Type your input here: DEFAULT
```

and after pressing backspace 3 times the user would see:

```
Type your input here: DEFA
```

Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192659/bash-user-prompt-default-input-text) have indicated that this isn't something you can do in, say, bash, but is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: Which OS are you using? In the case of Linux please check that this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible/2533142#2533142

Comment: As @HetalThaker suggested a post, [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyreadline3/) is something for windows similar to that. Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks @YashvanderBamel looks like this is what I was looking for. Should have looked harder. I'll close this question

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No.  It's just not something you can do in a console app.  What's commonly done is to display the default you'll get if you press return:

```
Type your input here [DEFAULT]:
```